# Flutter Locale property

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

Tryed to make the Provider LocaleProvider. But get the Error "Non-nullable instance field '_locale' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'." making it "late" gets me the error "The following LateError was thrown building Builder(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope]):
LateInitializationError: Field '_locale@23001738' has not been initialized."

```
class LocaleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Locale _locale;

  Locale get locale => _locale;

  void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    if (!L10n.all.contains(locale)) return;

    _locale = locale;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearLocale() {
    _locale = const Locale('en');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a constructor

```
class LocaleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Locale _locale;

  LocaleProvider(this._locale);//constructor for field initialization

  Locale get locale => _locale;

  void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    if (!L10n.all.contains(locale)) return;

    _locale = locale;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearLocale() {
    _locale = const Locale('en');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```